# Horn artefacts while using notch=True with matplotlib's boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I decided today to change my boxplots to include the notch command, and now I realised that some weird horn artefacts appear in some data as in the example to the far left and far right. The horns has nothing to do with the data, I have made sure that the box is otherwise the right size.

[image: Example plot]

Here is the boxplot command I use:

`ax.boxplot(abunds, sym='+', vert=1, whis='range', showfliers=True, showmeans=False, meanline=False, medianprops=medianlineprops, notch=True, patch_artist=True)`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird behavior of matplotlibs boxplot when using the notch shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291082/weird-behavior-of-matplotlibs-boxplot-when-using-the-notch-shape)

Comment: this is correct behaviour, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291082/weird-behavior-of-matplotlibs-boxplot-when-using-the-notch-shape and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3631

Answer (score 0):

It is not an artifact. It means that R has calculated that notch extends beyond the lower part of the IQR.

Comment: What does `R` have to do with `Python` in this case? Is there a way to remove these "features" then?

Comment: I assume that python and R do the same calculation. In R the way of eliminating the feature is to use notch = FALSE.

Comment: But that will remove the notches, and put me back to where I started from. Is there a way to adjust the angle of these notches, so that the notchs' extent are much shorter?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `bootstrap=1000` option. As reported in  http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html:

> Otherwise, bootstrap specifies the number of times to bootstrap the median to determine it’s 95% confidence intervals. Values between 1000 and 10000 are recommended.

and your line code:

```
ax.boxplot(abunds, sym='+', vert=1, whis='range', showfliers=True, showmeans=False, meanline=False, medianprops=medianlineprops, notch=True, patch_artist=True, bootstrap=1000)
```