# Interpretation of boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I am trying to create a box plot with matplotlib library of python. The code is given below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
bp = ax.boxplot([corr_df['bi'], corr_df['ndsi'], corr_df['dbsi'], corr_df['mbi']], patch_artist = True, notch ='True', vert = 1)
ax.set_title("Spearman’s correlation coefficient for Soil indices", fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("Indices", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Spearman’s correlation coefficient", fontsize=14)
colors = ['#088A08', '#FFFF00','#01DFD7', '#FF00FF', '#3A01DF']
for patch, color in zip(bp['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xticklabels(['bi', 'ndsi', 'dbsi', 'mbi'])
```

This creates an image like this :
[image: Flipped Appearance]

I am not able to understand the 1st and 3rd boxplot. These two (box plots of *bi* and *dbsi*) have neck-like structures in them, which the other two boxplots don't have. **What does this show?** The interpretation of the boxplot as described on the web doesn't include this part.

Comment: Also note that writing `notch='True'` with quotes isn't a valid value. It shouldn't be a string, but either the boolean value `True` or `False`, or `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the argument `notch` is set to `True` so according to the [doc,](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html#:%7E:text=array%20in%20x.-,notchbool,-%2C%20default%3A%20False) it displays:

> **notch** **bool, default: False**
> Whether to draw a notched boxplot (True), or a rectangular boxplot (False). The notches represent the confidence interval (CI) around the median. The documentation for bootstrap describes how the locations of the notches are computed by default, but their locations may also be overridden by setting the conf_intervals parameter.

Specifically the behavior (flipped appearance) you're describing is documented as follow:

> **Note**
>
> In cases where the values of the CI are less than the lower quartile
> or greater than the upper quartile, the notches will extend beyond the
> box, giving it a distinctive "flipped" appearance. This is expected
> behavior and consistent with other statistical visualization packages.

You will find more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291082/weird-behavior-of-matplotlibs-boxplot-when-using-the-notch-shape).